# Is this sentence ambiguous about when the events happened?

Tags: word-order

If I write the following sentence, how would it be understood?

> She took a shower, and she called for pizza delivery twelve minutes ago.

Would "twelve minutes ago" be understood to apply to both the actions, or just the last one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sentence structurally implies that she first took a shower and that twelve minutes before you wrote the sentence, she called to ask for a pizza to be delivered somewhere, probably to her place.

The 12-minute gap applies only to the time before the phone call for the pizza, not to when she took a shower. It could be the answer to the question:

> Q: What did she do today?
>   A: She took a shower. She also called for a pizza twelve minutes ago.

To make connections, other words are needed, e.g.:

> She finished taking a shower twelve minutes ago, and then she called to have a pizza delivered.